# Where to place code which synchronizes state of Redux with localStorage?

Tags: architecture, reactjs, redux

In our project, I was need to sync a piece of information between `localStorage` and the Redux state. Actually I subscribed to changes in a `localStorage` and in Redux, and if change happens in `localStorage` I update the state, and vice versa.

Right now I've created a redux enhancer for that. My coworker, however, claims that it isn't enhancing store functionality, and recommends to use a component, a content-provider or a fragment for that.

As doing it inside Redux' reducers is not recommended, as the reducers should be pure functions, where am I expected to put this sort of side effects?

Comment: 1. Where exactly your colleague suggests to put this code instead of the enhancer? 2. Do you synchronize *everything* in the store, or just specific pieces of information from the store?

Comment: In a `Component`, `Content-Provider` or `Fragments `. It should sync only JWT token. I must admit, that I relatively new in a react, only one month. In Vue, I would has done this functionality in an `Action`. But according to Dan Abramov, Redux' Reducer must be pure functions, so it should be done in other place. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305661/where-to-write-to-localstorage-in-a-redux-app

Comment: Indeed, reducers shouldn't have side effects. There are a bunch of articles such as [this one](https://goshakkk.name/redux-side-effect-approaches/) explaining where to put code which has side effects. I'm sorry, I don't have enough skills in React-Redux to be able to tell if those articles are correct or not, neither to write an answer to your question. I'm also surprised I can't find any answer on the subject here, on SE.SE. I therefore reworded your question a bit to make it more specific and reduce the risk of being closed/downvoted.